Python: headless mode in Playwright doesn't work
I have a really strange problem: starting my program with this headless=False option everything works correctly, pages are opened, buttons are clicked, in a nutshell Playwright does its job. As soon as I remove the headless mode or put headless=True, the program starts but closes after 1-2 seconds, doing absolutely nothing. (I notice this because it should return a .txt file to me).
PlaywrightAutomation.py



from playwright.sync_api import Playwright


class PlaywrightAutomation:
    def __init__(self, playwright: Playwright):
        self.playwright = playwright

    def start_driver(self, url):
        browser = self.playwright.chromium.launch(
            headless=False,
            args=[
                "--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 "
                "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36",
                "--log-level=3",
                '--no-sandbox',
                "--enable-automation=False",
                "--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled",
                "--window-size='1920,1080'",
                "--start-maximized"
            ]
        )
        context = browser.new_context(no_viewport=True)
        page = context.new_page()
        page.goto(url)
        return browser, context, page

    @staticmethod
    def press_button(page, prompt):
        page.wait_for_selector(prompt, state="visible")
        page.click(prompt)




This file is called from another file.py:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
from PlaywrightAutomation import PlaywrightAutomation


def playwright_stuffs(url, day):
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        automation = PlaywrightAutomation(p)
        b, c, pg = automation.start_driver(url)

        ...
        ...
        ...

        html_content = pg.content()

        c.close()
        b.close()

        with open(f'pinnacle_{day}.txt', 'w') as file:
            file.write(html_content)

        return html_content


def main():
    def pinnacle_day(day):
        html = playwright_stuffs('...', day)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    ...
    ...
    ...

    days = ['Lunedì', 'Martedì', 'Mercoledì', 'Giovedì', 'Venerdì', 'Sabato', 'Domenica']

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=len(days)) as executor:
        executor.map(pinnacle_day, days)


main()



I wouldn't really know what to try, because in headless=False everything works perfectly.
